# Woocommerce: hook action/filter I could use to add variation id and price with each attribute opt on WooCommerce Rest api

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, rest-api

I'm building a mobile app using wooCommerce REST API and need to inject the variations Id with the price in each attr option on REST API Product response.

**So the final response ( results ) of a product be something similar to this: ( What I need )**

```
{ 
  ...
  attributes: [
    id: 0,
    name: 'somthing',
    options: [
      { option: 'options one', varation_id: 123456, price: '5.5' }
      ...
    ]  
  ]
  ...
}
```

**Instead of the default one that looks like this:**

```
{ 
  ...
  attributes: [
    id: 0,
    name: 'somthing',
    options: [
      'option one',
      'option two',
      'option three'
      ...
    ]  
  ]
  ...
}
```